# How to graphically interpret the Chain Rule?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I'm having trouble trying to visualize graphically the Chain Rule.

When finding the derivative of a function $f$ with respect to $x$ at some point $x = a$ we write $f'(a)$, and this notation denotes that we are looking for the instant rate of change of $f$ at $x = a$. In other words, we are evaluating $f'$ at $x = a$. Graphically, this would be the tangent line to the curve $f$ at $x = a$.

For the Chain Rule, we have

$$f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

I think the derivative of $g$ is pretty straight forward since it's being differentiated with respect to $x$. It's the $f'$ that I'm having trouble visualizing graphically since it's being evaluated at the output of $g(x)$ instead of $x$.

When $x = a$, then $g(a)$ which means $f'(g(a))$. So the tangent line to $f$ is occurring at a point $g(a)$? But on which axis is the point $g(a)$ occurring, is it the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis or maybe some other third axis? I'm not sure how to interpret this graphically since I'm only familiar with using $x = a$ as the point at which a tangent line occurs to a curve.

Comment: where this law has its more pictorially rich interpretation is in its version on several variables, for example the case $\mathbb R^1\dashrightarrow \mathbb R^2\dashrightarrow \mathbb R^3$, in which one has control of the tangent vector along a curve on a surface in the 3d-space

Answer (score 1):

$f'(g(a))$ is the slope of $f(x)$ at $x=g(a)$

However say I have:

$h(x) = f(g(x))$

Then

$h'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$ (this is the chain rule)

So if I want the slope of $h(x)$ at $x=a$ that would be $h'(a) = f'(g(a))g'(a)$

Try this with an example. Say

$$f(x)=x^2$$

$$g(x) = x+3$$

$$h(x) = f(g(x)) = (x+3)^2$$

So the $f'(g(a))$ is like an intermediate value I use to then calculate $h'(a)$.

Try calculating $h'(x)$ directly first. Then try calculating $h'(x)$ using the chain rule. Also try graphing and seeing the results. You will see that the slope of f(x) at $x=g(a)$ is $f'(g(a))$